# Change the font of the site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

For some reason, Electrical Engineering has a different font compared to the other SO sites. It appears to be Times New Roman or something similar: a font suitable for letters, books and fiction.

Is there a rationale behind this?

I find posts on this site far less readable than those on the other sites of the SO network. The font is particularly bad when you paste source code, mathematical/electrical formulas and similar, and forget to put it inside `code tags`.

I would like to see this site using the same font as the other SO sites.

Comment: For reference, here is the relevant post in favor of the serif font: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/449/638

Comment: I agree, it's a combination of the font with the background grid. Also I don't like how numbers like 4 and 9 are at different line heights than other numbers. I don't know what that's called or why it is but it looks weird.

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie It's called [Text Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_style_figures) or [Oldstyle Figures](http://fontfeed.com/archives/figuring-it-out-osf-lf-and-tf-explained/) and I hate them and serifs when they're rendered in pixels. Yet I prefer them when rendered in ink and pulp.

Comment: I agree that the font isn't the best, but the look is not a big deal to me. What bothers me most is how digits look. Some have decenders or are shown lower contrary to convention and for no apparent reason. Digits: 0123456789. The way 3, 4, and 5 are lower can only be called "stupid". I can sortof see longer tails on 7 and 9, but the whole digit is lower. More stupidity. Actually the only ones that look right are 6 and 8. The remainder are either squashed or lowered for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, graphic designers and historians seem to like those old-style figures. I prefer them in history books where most of the numbers are years and dates, like 23 July, 1906. But I agree modern figures (without descenders, etc.) are easier to read for the kind of text we're writing here.

Comment: FWIW body copy is using the typesets `Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;` in that order (as if in you don't have Georgia you get TNR)

Comment: I agree that a sans-serif font would probably be a better fit for electronics.SE. I believe Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, or similar would be a better pick.

Comment: The numerals are unbearable. Someone in charge please change them to something reasonable. It is the biggest design oversight in all of EE.SE. Even when I first started visiting the sight I thought "wtf is with these numbers?"