# Change the way digits are displayed, get rid of non-lining digits

Tags: feature-request

In the comments of [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2509/9730) post, I brought up that I can't stand how numbers are displayed. [@embedded.kyle](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10045/embedded-kyle) pointed out that it's called [Text Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_style_figures) or [Oldstyle Figures](http://fontfeed.com/archives/figuring-it-out-osf-lf-and-tf-explained/). And [@Olin Lathrop](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4512/olin-lathrop) explained the issue:

> What bothers me most is how digits look. Some have decenders or are
>   shown lower contrary to convention and for no apparent reason. Digits:
>   0123456789. The way 3, 4, and 5 are lower can only be called "stupid". I can sortof see longer tails on 7 and 9, but the whole digit is
>   lower. More stupidity. Actually the only ones that look right are 6
>   and 8. The remainder are either squashed or lowered for some
>   unfathomable reason.

It seems like most people would like digits to be displayed normally. So can we change this?

**Edit**

Screenshot of the above quoted comment for those users without the Georgia font installed (secondary fonts like Times New Roman have lining numerals):

[image]

Comment: Although they may not please people, I think that the font has its own sense. If you look at numbers, they are kinda like lowercase letters, with the "heaviest" part in the middle and smaller glyphs up or down. I don't know who takes care of the design, but everything can be changed at will.

Comment: Ask any font designer why they made this or that design decision and I'm sure they will have a reason (or list of reasons) that makes sense to them. I went to a [Typography Exhibit at MoMA](http://www.moma.org/explore/inside_out/2011/01/24/digital-fonts-23-new-faces-in-moma-s-collection) once and they went into the psychology and sociology behind various fonts. I don't really understand _why_ I prefer Oldstyle numbers in books but prefer Lining numbers on a screen. But I do. +1

Comment: And the digits in your quote on Olin's comment are still appearing Oldstyle to me at the moment so I don't think it's been changed yet.

Comment: Can you give a link to this discussion?

Comment: @Kortuk First link in the post. Refers to the the comments of this Meta post: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/change-the-font-of-the-site

Comment: I was scrolled down just perfectly to miss the first line when I was reading it. Since that was exactly your first sentence a partial sentence did not tip me off! Sorry.

Comment: @clabacchio: But there seems to be no consistant scheme to the digits we have now. 0, 1, and 2 are squashed, 3, 4, 5, 7, and 9 lowered, and 6 and 8 normal. If all were one way at least you can make the case they were designed to a theme. What we have now is just a stupid looking mess.

Comment: @embedded.kyle Thanks, they are not appearing old style to me, so I thought that maybe they changed it; however I had just installed a new linux OS so my other thought was that I just don't have that font installed. They still appear normal to me so that must be the problem. If you can, could you take a screenshot and add it to my post (I will when I have access to another computer.) Thanks!

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie Done. In the previous post, Ben Brocka lists the available fonts in order. You're probably missing Georgia and so reverting to Times New Roman.

Comment: @embedded.kyle, thank you very much!

Comment: @OlinLathrop: for the font choice, you can blame the designer; but for the style of numbers, it's specified in the Georgia font, and as I thought is to match lowercase letters. (Found in Wikipedia right now)

Comment: @clabacchio: Then it still doesn't make sense that 3 is different from 8, although the 3 is shown low and the 8 normal.

Comment: The argument isn't about whether the font makes sense or not, but rather why it was chosen for this site. I'd perhaps pick that font if I wanted to put a label on my RL physical mailbox, but I would not use it in any mathematical/scientific context.

Comment: So the three doesn't match to what you learned at primary school, but do you still write the way you were tought back then? Like there is no bad-hand-writing-police, there is also no bad-font-police. Apart from the fact that I don't think it is a bad font, on contrary. I think it is a perfectly good font. Things change, it is part of life. Better worry about things that do matter.

Comment: @jippie because it is harder to read, a bit aggravating and a lot (probably most) people don't like it. This is a community driven site and it is simple to change. It's not asking for the moon, and these types of issues are what Meta is for. I don't mind the font except for how digits are displayed.

Comment: @jippie No bad-hand-writing-police? Tell that to my 5th grade teacher. She made me stay in every day for a month during recess to work on my handwriting. She finally gave up and I still can't read what I write.

Comment: @embedded.kyle you were supposed to believe in Santa and the tooth fairy too ...

Comment: There's another math-rich SE site that uses Georgia for post text: namely, [math.SE]. You may be interested in the [discussion of the same issue there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10317/).

Answer (score 3):

Font by itself is kind of nice for me (even numbers), if I was reading about that famous detective John Smith and what he is doing in front of house number 42 in the middle of the night. But for scientific oriented text is utterly s... stupid(just to be polite). When single digit is used, then it is somehow acceptable, but for longer strings like 0987654321 it is simply awful and extremely annoying. Every taste is different so probably won't be bad idea to be a choice in a user preferences. Still more technical font will be more appropriate for electronics. There are reason why technical fonts exist in first place and readability and unambiguity are among if not prime ones.