# Didn't we switch the site style to use "lining" numerals?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Sometime last year [a discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/change-the-way-digits-are-displayed-get-rid-of-non-lining-digits) in Meta resulted in the site style changed to use lining numerals instead of "old style".

Today, it looks like the old style numerals came back.

Anybody know what's up?

Comment: I never saw the old style numerals go away.  There was never a change that I noticed.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked through the change logs, and I'm fairly certain that the style never changed.